# MongoDB - Search by insertion order (date) sub-value

Tags: sql, mongodb, date, field

Think you can give me your help on MongoDB .

My scheme is for example :

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 538339ef5b17848a488b7e35
    )
    [group_name] => 'group 1'
    [activity] => Array
    (
        [open] => Array
        (
            [company] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 1
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1400081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                ),
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 2
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1500081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                ),
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 3
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1600081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                ),
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 4
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1700081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 538339ef5b178424498b7e34
    )
    [group_name] => 'group 2'
    [activity] => Array
    (
        [open] => Array
        (
            [company] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 3
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1300081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                ),
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 1
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1600081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                ),
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 2
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1800081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                ),
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company 4
                    [date] => MongoDate Object
                    (
                        [sec] => 1900081160
                        [usec] => 0
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And infact I would fill display the "groupname" only if such insertion order by DATE is "Company 1, Company 2, Company 3". 
So normally it should show me in the example above only "Group 1", because the order is as required, while in the "Group 2" order starts with "Business 3, followed by Company 1. ... ".

--

For example if I'm looking like this:

```
[activity.open.company] => Array
(
    [$in] => Array
        (
            [0] => company 1
            [1] => company 2
            [2] => company 3
        )

)
```

This will highlight my whole world and not just the "Group 1"

--

Thank you sincerely for your help!

PS : Sorry for my english, I'm french.

Answer (score 0):

When you query with an `$in` clause it basically becomes and `$or` on the items of the given array. The query you have written *would* match the two documents listed because they both have at least company 2 in them.